# Converting files to S2 cell IDs

Tags: shapefile, geohash

I would like to use Google's S2 library to convert geospatial data (for instance shapefiles or geojson files) to S2 cell IDs.
The data I want to convert is made of polygons.
I saw there exists this [repository](https://github.com/micolous/s2-geometry-library) which enables the use of the S2 library in Python, but the S2Polygon object is not implemented.
Otherwise, I found this very nice [tool](https://github.com/micolous/maptz) which converts shapefiles to S2 IDs, but can't make it work on files other than those given in the example, it might be due to my files.
I have also found a [Go implementation](https://github.com/golang/geo) of the library, but it doesn't fully implement the S2Polygon object either.

Is there such a tool or function, other than the C++ S2 library ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this repository
https://github.com/micolous/s2-geometry-library

Some examples:

```
import s2

latlng = s2.S2LatLng.FromDegrees(-30.043800, -51.140220)
cell = s2.S2CellId.FromLatLng(latlng)

cell.level()
30

cell.id()
10743750136202470315

cell.ToToken()
951977d377e723ab
```